# React Element change class onClick

Tags: node.js, reactjs, pagination

I have created a custom pagination in React: 
I basically have in the container pagination which will be visible only when data is received:

```
...
    {this.state.displayTweets.length != 0 && <Pagination pageCount={this.state.pageCount} pagination={this.pagination.bind(this)}/>}
...
```

This is the function that is called when a pagination item is clicked:

```
pagination(data){
        if(data == -1 && offset>0){
            console.log("Previous")
            offset -= perPage
            this.setState({displayTweets: this.state.tweets.slice(offset,offset+perPage)})
        } else if(data == 0 && pageNumber < this.state.pageCount) {
            console.log("Next")
            pageNumber += 1
            offset += perPage
            this.setState({displayTweets: this.state.tweets.slice(offset,offset+perPage)});
        } else if(data > 0 && data < this.state.pageCount){
            console.log("Between")
            pageNumber = data
            offset = perPage*(data-1)
            this.setState({displayTweets: this.state.tweets.slice(offset,perPage*data)});
        }
        console.log("Page number: "+pageNumber)
        console.log("Offset: "+offset)
    }
```

And here is the actual Pagination component:

```
import React from 'react';

const PageLi = (props) => {
    let pages = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= props.pageCount; i++) {
        pages.push(<li className="page-item" onClick={() => { props.pagination(i)}} key={i}><a className="page-link">{i}</a></li>);
    }
    return (
        <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
            <ul className="pagination">
                <li className="page-item" onClick={() => { props.pagination(-1)}}><a className="page-link">Previous</a></li>
                {pages}
                <li className="page-item"><a onClick={() => { props.pagination(0)}} className="page-link">Next</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    );
};

export default PageLi;
```

Everything works as expected. Now I would like that when I click on a pagination item to change the class from `page-item` to `page-item-active` and remove the `active part` from the previously clicked one. How can I do this in React? I know that I can set states, but to have a state for each page number would be stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store and maintain your current page number also in your state and then pass it as a prop to PageLi component. Then you can do something as follows to change the class based on current page number.

```
let pages = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= props.pageCount; i++) {
  pages.push(
    <li
      className={i === props.pageNumber ? "page-item-active" : "page-item"}
      onClick={() => {
        props.pagination(i);
      }}
      key={i}
    >
      <a className="page-link">{i}</a>
    </li>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Smart idea. I really like it.

Comment: Would you have any idea on how to display points in the pagination? Because I usually end up with 25+pages and it looks ugly to have all of them displayed.

Comment: You can write some if else logic with pageNumber in the for loop and push a different component for dots while `continue` loop for page numbers that you don't want to show